# Is this weak asymptotic Goldbach's conjecture open?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory, goldbach-type-problems

Let $\tau(x)$ be the number of even numbers $2<2n<x$ which can't be written as a sum of two primes.

*Goldbach's conjecture*: $\tau(x) = 0$
*Asymptotic Goldbach's conjecture*:  $\tau(x) = O(1) $

*Weak asymptotic Goldbach's conjecture*:  $\tau(x) = \omicron (\frac{x}{ln(x)}) $

**Question**: Is this weak asymptotic Goldbach's conjecture open ?
What's the better estimate known?

---

**Application**: Given an odd prime number $p$,   there are odd prime numbers $q$, $p'$, $q'$  such that $\{p,q\} \neq \{ p',q'\}$  and   $p+q = p'+q'$.

As explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868224/is-this-goldbach-type-problem-easy-to-solve/868478#868478), we need something slightly stronger for this application: $\tau_2(x) = \omicron (x/ln(x)) $, with $τ_2(x)$ the number of even numbers $2<2n<x$ that can't be written as a sum of two distinct pairs of primes. Is it known ?

Comment: Montgomery and Vaughan showed that the exceptional set in Goldbach's conjecture contains at most $O(x^{1-\delta})$ elements for some $\delta >0$.  See http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa27/aa27126.pdf .

Comment: @Lucia: Yes it's exactly what I expected, thank you !

Comment: What does "cte" mean?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: "cte" means "constant". I'm sorry, the standard abbreviation is rather "cst"...

Comment: $\text{const}$ or $O(1)$ would have required less head-scratching for me.

Comment: I just read your application. I believe it follows more directly, namely a variant of Vinogradov's proof for the ternary Goldbach problem should yield that: any odd number $p$ can be written as $p'+q'-q$ with three primes $p',q',q$. In general, solving a linear equation in three prime variables avoiding the obvious obstructions (e.g. modulo $2$) can be done by the circle method. There is no need to switch to a binary problem.

Comment: @GHfromMO:  Does the Vinogradov's proof gives a slightly more (because $p=p+q-q$) ?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux: All these proofs yield that the number of representations is roughly the same (up to a log-power) as if the variables were not primes. That is, and you are right to ask for clarification, the number of solutions of $p=p'+q'-q$ with $x/2<p',q',q<x$ primes should be about $x^2$, in fact Vinogradov's method surely yields $\asymp x^2/\log^3 x$. In particular, most solutions are nontrivial, i.e. $q$ differs from $p'$ and $q'$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The weak asymptotic Goldbach conjecture was proved by Chudakov in 1937 (based on the groundbreaking work of Vinogradov). Better bounds are known, see Lucia's comment. The preprint [arXiv:1804.09084](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.09084) by Pintz shows that $\tau(x)<x^{0.72}$ for $x$ sufficiently large.

You can find the original reference and a modern treatment in Vaughan's book "The Hardy-Littlewood method".

**Added.** My response and Lucia's comment hold verbatim for $τ_2$. In fact Montgomery-Vaughan proved that for all but $O(x^{1−δ})$ even integers $x/2<2n<x$, the number of representations $2n=p+q$  is at least $x^{1−3δ}$. Here $δ$ is any sufficiently small positive number, and the implied constant depends only on $δ$. See Section $8$ in the Montgomery-Vaughan paper.

Comment: Let $τ_2(x)$ be the number of even numbers $2<2n<x$ that can't be written as a sum of two distinct pairs of primes. Do you know if we have similar bounds for $τ$ and $τ_2$ ? Perhaps this question requires to open another post, what do you think?

Comment: @Sébastien: The mentioned results not only prove that most even numbers can be written as a sum of two primes, but also that they can be written as a sum of two primes in many ways. Look up Vaughan's book and the Montgomery-Vaughan paper (referred in my response and Lucia's comment).

Comment: Ok, thank you! Do you know if these results allow to keep similar bounds for $\tau_2$  (see the application I've edited) ?  I will look the paper more closely.

Comment: Yes, see the added section in my response.

Comment: Does this also mean that the Asymptotic Goldbach conjecture is open?

Comment: @AdamRubinson Yes, it is widely open. The best known result is that $\tau(x)<x^{0.72}$ for $x$ sufficiently large. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.09084